# subdomains + nginx + reverse proxy + jenkins + gitlab

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, jenkins, server, dns

Searching the internet for the complete guide and explanation on how to run website + jenkins + gitlab like so:

- Jenkins @ jenkins.domain.com
- GitLab @ gitlab.domain.com
- static website @ domain.com

ie Specific services on a server and have access to them via subdomains, I haven't found and answer.

We are running ubuntu, nginx and have a domain name example.com and an A record pointing to our ip address 111.111.111.111

We can see the nginx welcome page.

How are the subdomains resolved? Where to create them?
Can our server become a DNS?
What should be the final nginx conf?

This one is wrong, since it needs to serve static website and tries to serve static files for jenkins and that results in a 404.

```
server {
  access_log        logs/landing.access.log;
  server_name       example.com;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  Host $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  location / {
    root /var/www/html/landing;
    index index.html;
  }

  location /app {
    proxy_pass      http://localhost:9981;
  }

  location ^~ /jenkins {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:9990;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;

    # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
    proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:9990 $scheme://example.com;

    # Optionally, require HTTP basic auth.
    # auth_basic "Please authenticate to use Jenkins";
    # auth_basic_user_file /opt/nginx/htpasswd;
  }
}
```

Should there be another server block then?

```
server {
  access_log        logs/jenkins.access.log;
  server_name       jenkins example.com;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  Host $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:9990;
}
```

But this one gives a 404 for a different reason, I assume this 2nd block clashes with the first one, as I am trying to access it via example.com not subdomain.example.com. And subdomain.example.com is not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you have a few different questions. First DNS related questions. If you have domain.tld then you go to whomever manages the DNS for that domain and add a `CNAME` or `A` record which points to your `nginx` server.

As for your `Jenkins` `nginx` setup. I would create a new file like `jenkins.domain.tld.conf` and put in this which I copied from [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy)

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name jenkins.domain.tld;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://127.0.0.1:8080 https://jenkins.domain.tld;

      # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_request_buffering off;
      # workaround for https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45651
      add_header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' 'jenkins.domain.tld:50022' always;     
    }
  }
```

For each sub domain go to Google and search for *service* `nginx` and you should find advice on how do set it up.

Comment: Your nameservers would just point to your nginx server for each of the sub domains.

Comment: Do I have to define subdomains anywhere or they will work out of the box? If I write them in server blocks for nginx?

Comment: You define `server_name sub.domain.tld;` for each subdomain server block(s) and as long as DNS is pointing to that nginx server for that subdomain then nginx would handle it. If you don't have server blocks setup it goes to the default server block.

Comment: But that means I have to create subdomains as well? How do I do that? And where? I only have an a record for the domain.com A 111.111.111.111

Comment: Already in the answer "If you have domain.tld then you go to whomever manages the DNS for that domain and add a `CNAME` or `A` record which points to your `nginx` server."

Comment: So to sum up I need Jenkins.domain.com pointing to the same ip 111.111.111.111 and then my personal nginx will do the rest